# How do I verify if a file is being downloaded in Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, download, verify

How to verify file being downloaded. I am stuck at how do I retrieve the downloaded file when the "Download" button had been clicked.

```
''  driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.162.0.1/testing-admin/Login/Login.aspx");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_txtUserID")).SendKeys("Jojo");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_txtPassword")).SendKeys("Man15742368");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_cmdLogin")).Click();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.162.0.1/testing-admin/User_Document/User_Document_Download.aspx");
      driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='ctl00_MainContent_GV_ctl02_lnkDownloadFile']")).Click(); //download button
```

Comment: See if ChromeDriver allows you to do this https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/6317 or else try using FireFox..?

Comment: Isnt that just where you set your file download preference.

Comment: `how do I retrieve the downloaded file` -> you look in that folder for the file

Comment: Oh i c, let me give it  a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Path = "drive path";
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
co.AddAdditionalCapability("download.default_directory", Path);
driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
```

Then you can you System.IO.DirectoryInfo for retrieving all downloaded file details into Path folder.

Answer (score 0):

I used this, it work too. But the only downsize is that you have to know the name of the file you downloaded .

```
String myDownloadFolder = @"c:\temp\";
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", myDownloadFolder);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google/download/some"); // download some stuffs
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Download")).Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); 
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(@"c:\temp\Test.docx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the commands to set up ChromeDriver and verify file is downloaded successfully (tested with latest v121) -

```
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
                    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                    chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", fullPath);
                    chromeOptions.AddAdditionalOption("download.download.prompt_for_download", false);
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
                    // navigate to page and interact with it - download will happen automatically
                    File.Exists($"{fullPath}\{fileName}").Should().BeTrue();
```

**Note**: currently does not seem to work in Incognito